# uthentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile

Tags: ubuntu

здравствуйте.вот такая ошибка uthentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.подскажите что делать?

Comment: Покажите полный вывод ошибки и содержимое logfile.